# url parameter set by label value in Spring MVC

Tags: forms, url, spring-mvc

Is there any way to make form url parameter submit by value of label?

I mean, I want to do simple search form like this:

```
<form:form action="usersearch.do?searchName=....">
<input type="text" id="search" name="search"> <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form:form>
```

How to set url parameter "searchName" by value that was put in my form, like:
usersearch.do?searchName=JohnSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your form method to "GET" then the field names will be submitted on the query string. For example:

```
<form:form action="usersearch.do" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="searchName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form:form>
```

Will do result in a GET on a URL that looks like:

.../usersearch.do?searchName={formValue} e.g. JohnSmith